# RouterLink on div with @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I declared a div with routerLink. In previous versions this was working. Now (@angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3) it is not working.

Does anyone know a solution?

```
<a class="my-item" [routerLink]="['/hero']">...</a>
```

worked, but then I need to update my styles.

> browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known native property ("
>   [ERROR ->]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it seems there is issue in the updated routing of angular2, Now `routeLink` is only working with `a` tag neither on the button nor on div and so on, so as alternate if you want to use routing on div than you have to call click function and do routing in your controller part like this

```
<div class="my-item" (click)='routing()'></div>

...
constructor(private _router: Router)
routing(){
   this._router.navigate("['/hero']");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the correct directives into your component:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
```

and

```
@Component({
    <...>
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})
```

Please share your full component code if this is not working